# Can I put cavaquinho strings on a ukulele?

Tags: strings, ukulele

I have currently a concert ukulele that I'm not using and I would like to put on it steel cavaquinho strings in order to use it as a cavaquinho. Is it a bad idea ? Are there risks for my instrument ?

Answer (score 4):

It's always a bad idea to put steel strings on an instrument not designed for them.

The tension is a lot higher than nylon & could result in a bent neck, the bridge coming away or at worst a broken headstock or neck.

Comment: Yeah, that's typically why any ukuleles with any metal strings usually have a metal C-string or low G-string. Metal A string seems rather difficult to work with.